# Extract .NET code from React Native for Windows

Tags: ida, .net

I'm interested in reversing a UWP program made using [React Native for Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows). Once such applications are compiled, the logic is contained in one dll. After opening this dll into IDA, it appears pretty clear that the file contains a .NET part (located in the section `.rdata`) and generic stub as native code in the `.text` section.

Did anyone already succeed to extract the .NET code in the `.rdata` section and open it in a standard decompiler?

Cheers!

Comment: Is it not recognized as a .NET binary?

Comment: If I understand the concept correctly, the .net part is only to host the JS engine and the app itself is the react app. So not sure how much code you will get from it but try dnSpy. If that's not the case - please share mentioned dll